# siaqodb query: ArgumentException: The field handle and the type handle are incompatible

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

I am using the siaqodb plugin in Unity3D to manage my database game.

The plugin uses the System.LINQ library and I am having an specific problem:

The code:

```
var query = (from T t in siaqodb where t.Id == 1 select t);
return query.ToList<T> ()[0];
```

Works good! That's OK! Great!

But the code:

```
int a = 1;
var query = (from T t in siaqodb where t.Id == a select t);
return query.ToList<T> ()[0]
```

This code Throws the exception: 
***ArgumentException: The field handle and the type handle are incompatible.***

Comment: I've seen old bugs related to lambda expressions (which Linq uses) and mono (which Unity3D uses). I'd google for the exception text + "Mono" and see if it brings up. I don't have Mono or Unity3D handy to test :-/

Comment: What is type of `Id`? If it's long, try `1L` instead of `1`

Comment: @MustafaChelik I'd try `long a = 1`, not `1L`. The first code is the one working, isn't it? Anyway, an `int` to `long` conversion should be handled implicitly... in fact, it's what `t.Id == 1` would do in the first code example if `Id` was a `long`

Comment: Default integer numbers evaluates as `int`. That's weird. So what's type of `Id`?

Comment: @MustafaChelik right, but `int` is implicitly converted to `long`, `float`, `double`, or `decimal`, with no explicit cast necessary (check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx), so if `t.Id` is any of those types (and it is, since the first code snippet is working), the code should work.

Comment: I know but it's true about C# in VS, not mono. It can be a bug as you said. I would try writing it's type explicitly. I remember in android I had to cast explicitly (LinQ in android).

Comment: The implicit conversions are on the C# specification (section 6.1.2). Those are language specifications and are platform independent. If It's C#, it should adhere to the specs, if it doesn't, it's either not C#, or it's a bug (or lack of implementation). Since the code is C#, and the question tagged with C#, I'd presume it's the latter.

Comment: - Id is a int Type
- I have tried the long a = 1; and it didn't wok

Comment: That totally sounds like a bug in either Mono or the siaqodb linq provider. Since Mono is pretty mature, I'd bet for siaqodb.

Comment: People I tried the following code to test: 
  int i = 5;
  var q1 = from int a in new int[] {1,2,3,4,5} where a == i select a;      Debug.Log (q1.ToList<int> () [0]);
This woks good, I think it is a siaqodb problem

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem using the following code:

```
var query = (from T t in siaqodb select t);
return query.ToList<T> ().Where (t => t.Id == id).ToList ()[0];
```

This is not pretty but I could avoid the ArgumentException where I believe it happened in the Reflection code from siaqodb...

Comment: The problem with this is that you are retrieving the whole set in memory, and filtering afterwards with linq-to-objects. If there are many records in the db, this could be problematic/slow/a memory hog

Answer (score 0):

I came across with this error too, the problem seams to be that Generic types and Lamda expressions are incompatible in SQLite. The expression uses the Generic base type or interface, and is trying to get it from DB, but you are not storing the Base type or interface, you are storing a derivative. If you use lambdas, you have to use the correct type that matches the DB table.